# $f^3$ integrable $\implies f$ integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, examples-counterexamples

Let $R \subset \mathbb R^n$ a "brick" and $f ∶ R → \mathbb R$  a bounded function. We denote by $ℛ(R)$ the space of Riemann-integrable functions on R. Is the following statement true ?
$$f^3 \in ℛ(R) \implies f \in ℛ(R)$$

I know that $f^2 \in ℛ(R) \implies f \in ℛ(R)$ is false by taking $n=1$, $R=[0,1]$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x \in \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q$.
We have that $f^2=1 \forall x$ but $f$ is not integrable.

But I do not have any idea for the $f^3$ statement. I thought of taking something maybe with $n=3$ and also thought of $f(x)=\lfloor{1/x}\rfloor \mod 3 $ that can be interesting but it does not work. Maybe the statement is true. Any ideas ?

Comment: The cube root is a continuous function on $\Bbb R$

Comment: @MartinR But we could have said the same thing for $f^2$ since the square root is a continuous function on $\mathbb R^+$ but I gave a counter example.

Comment: Keep in mind the subtlety of roots vs principal roots here. The square root of $x^2$ (for $x\in\mathbb{R}$) is both $\pm x$. However, the principal square root of $x^2$ is $|x|$. The principal square root is well-defined as a function. The square root itself is not well-defined as a function since it is multi-valued. You don't work with general relations in analysis (or most of math), you work with well-defined functions. To that end, you are forced to adopt the principal square root (or the other one, but not both simultaneously like you're thinking).

Comment: @John: The difference is that the [cube root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root) is defined and continuous on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: So ultimately what you can conclude is that if $f^2$ is integrable, $|f|$ is integrable (and so is $-|f|$). You need extra information about $f$ to conclude that it is actually integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=x^{1/3}$, if $f^3$ is integrable then $g\circ f^3=f\Rightarrow \text{$f$ is integrable.}$

Comment: That is true, but a simple justification is required. For example, see MartinR comment above.