# What's wrong of my proof of that $f^2$ is Riemann integrable implies $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Tags: riemann-integration

Suppose $f$ is a bounded real function on $[a,b]$ and $f^2$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

$f^2$ is Riemann integrable does not imply $f$ is Riemann integrable. As an example, $f = -1$ when $x$ is irrational; $f = 1$ when $x$ is rational.

However, if $f^3$ is Riemann integrable, then $f$ is Riemann integrable because: if $f^3$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then $[f(a)]^3\le f^3 \le [f(b)]^3$. Since $g(u) = u^\frac13$ is obiviously on $[[f(a)]^3, [f(b)]^3], g[f^3(x)] = f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

What if I use $\psi(u) = u^\frac12$ to replace the  $g(u)$ above, then we can prove that $f^2$ is Riemann integrable implies $f$ is Riemann integrable, doesn't it? But this is wrong. Then, what's wrong with the later proof?

Comment: Why not carefully write down the "proof" applied to your specific counterexample and see which steps work amd which steps do not?

Comment: Just because $f^3$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, doesn't necessarily mean that $a^3 \leq f^3 \leq b^3$.

Comment: ψ(u) = u^(1/2) is not defined for $u <0$.

Comment: If someone writes a good answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186911/f3-integrable-implies-f-integrable) we effectively get a dupe candidate. Basically Cameron Williams' comments there form the answer to this question.

Comment: @JasonDeVito One problem I found may be $\psi(u) = u^\frac12$ . However, I don't know how to describe the problem exactly. Could you please offer me a statement? Thanks very much!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer   Sorry, I made such a big mistake. I've corrected it.

Comment: Maybe I understand. $\psi(u) = [f(x)^2]^\frac12$ does not equals $ f $; it's just seems like to be the same; but actually $f < 0$ will happen while $\psi(u) = [f(x)^2]^\frac12 < 0$ won't.

Comment: @KentonPendragonSu exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u^{1/2}$ is not onto, unlike $u^{1/3}$. You already gave a counterexample. How can you reconstruct $-1$ from $1^{1/2}=1$? You cannot just randomly choose different root for $u^{1/2}$. Because such choice won't be (Riemann) integrable in general. And secondly picking $-1$ instead of $1$ for $1^{1/2}$ will reconstruct $-1$, but now you lose $1$!

When we talk about $u^{1/2}$ we only consider **non-negative** root, because this choice leads to good properties (continuous, integrable, etc.). Unlike $u^{1/3}$ which is a well defined homeomorphism, and no choice is involved here (the equation $x^3=u$ has a single solution).

So in reality, $\big(f^{2}\big)^{1/2}\neq f$. This is true only when $f\geq 0$ to begin with, in fact $\big(f^{2}\big)^{1/2}=|f|$ (the absolute value). While $\big(f^{3}\big)^{1/3}= f$ is always true.

Note that you did show something though. That if $f^2$ is Riemann integrable then so is $|f|$.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between $g$ and $\psi$ is that it is true that $f=g\circ f^3$, but it is **not** always true that $f=\psi\circ f^2$. For example, whenever $f(x)$ is negative, you have $\psi(f^2(x)) = -f(x)$.